# Is there a way to identify whether or not a person is in a specified group in Active Directory, even if the group is several levels deep

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, active-directory

Sometimes the architecture in active directory is very complicated. There are many groups in my AD and they are hierarchical.

Take this for example:
Group A is the top group, it has a child Group B, and Group B also has a child C. C is the leaf node and it is a person in AD. Is there an approach to identify C is a member of Group A.

I can do this by enumerating the "memberof" property recursively in AD. But is there a more efficient mechanism to do that work?

I need to do that in .NET with C#. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [UserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.userprincipal.getauthorizationgroups.aspx).  It's giving you all the groups in the token, as mentioned by Swanny

Comment: Thanks, it said "This function only returns groups that are security groups; distribution groups are not returned." any way, it is worth a try.

Comment: That's correct.  The token mentioned by Swanny doesn't include distribution group anyway.  BTW, you may also want to check out Principal.IsMemberOf which can help you do "memberOf" LDAP query and return you the Princiapl object.  Principal.IsMemberOf() can find out all the Distribution Group.

Comment: I have tested it. Principal.IsMemberOf() can not work if there are several levels. Does that mean I also need to use a recursive function to identify it?

Comment: Yes, it can only find one level of membership.  This is documented in MSDN too.  My comment meant that instead of creating the LDAP query yourself, you can use this function instead.  The nice thing of this function is that it does more than just querying "memberOf" attribute.  It also takes care the primary group settings.  So, even though "Domain Users" is not explicity set in the "memberOf" attribute of your user.  IsMemberOf() function can still correctly find it out.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is a better way these days but this is how we did it back on the .Net 1.0 day. There is a method I think called GetTokens() or something like that. It might only be available via the COM interface (so you need to wrap it in an interop). It gives you back a list of SIDs for each thing that the user is ultimately a member of (even if a group within a group within a group) and then you can just get the SID of the group your interested in and check whether it is in the list returned earlier. 
Getting the list of SIDs is a little resource heavy so you might want to cache the result. If you make lots of calls at once you can slow the AD down.

Comment: Thanks. Harvey Kwok mentioned a function UserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroups. it is in framework 3.5 and 4.